# how to convert string to timestamptype in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, datetime-format

I have a csv file with below data

```
Tran_id,Tran_date1,Tran_date2,Tran_date3
1,2022-07-02T16:53:30.375Z,2022-07-02T16:53:30.3750000+00:00,2022-07-02 16:53:30.3750000+00:00
2,2022-08-02T17:33:10.456Z,2022-08-02T17:33:10.4560000+00:00,2022-08-02 17:33:10.4560000+00:00
3,2022-09-02T18:13:20.375Z,2022-09-02T18:13:20.3750000+00:00,2022-09-02 18:13:20.3750000+00:00
4,2022-09-02T19:23:90.322Z,2022-09-02T19:23:90.3220000+00:00,2022-09-02 19:23:90.3220000+00:00
```

I want to read this csv file using pyspark and convert the data to below format

```
root
 |-- Tran_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Tran_date1: TimestampType(nullable = false)
 |-- Tran_date2: TimestampType(nullable = false)
 |-- Tran_date3: TimestampType(nullable = false)
```

and save this data into hive table by converting the string type to timestamptype

how to convert the string into timestamptype without losing the format

Comment: You cannot have both things in spark if you want to keep type then you will lose formatting and if you want to keep formatting then type will be string

Answer (score 1):

You could have read your csv file with automatic conversion to the required type, like this:

```scala
spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("test.csv")
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Tran_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date3: string (nullable = true)
```

But as you can see with your data it won't give you the correct schema. The reason is that you have some bad data in your csv. E.g. look at your record #4: 022-09-02T19:23:**90**.322Z, i.e. there can't be 90 seconds.

You can do the parsing yourself:

```scala
df = (
    spark.read
    .option("header","true")
    .csv("test.csv")
    .select(
    "Tran_id",
    F.to_timestamp("Tran_date1").alias("Tran_date1"),
    F.to_timestamp("Tran_date2").alias("Tran_date2"),
    F.to_timestamp("Tran_date3").alias("Tran_date3")))

# Schema is correct now
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Tran_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date2: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Tran_date3: timestamp (nullable = true)

# But we now have nulls for bad data
df.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|Tran_id|Tran_date1             |Tran_date2             |Tran_date3             |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1      |2022-07-02 16:53:30.375|2022-07-02 16:53:30.375|2022-07-02 16:53:30.375|
|2      |2022-08-02 17:33:10.456|2022-08-02 17:33:10.456|2022-08-02 17:33:10.456|
|3      |2022-09-02 18:13:20.375|2022-09-02 18:13:20.375|2022-09-02 18:13:20.375|
|4      |null                   |null                   |null                   |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

With the correct schema in place, you can later save you dataframe to hive, spark will take care of preserving the types.

Comment: how can we have exactly the same 2022-07-02T16:53:30.375Z     2022-07-02T16:53:30.3750000+00:00  values in timestamp datatype column in hive and how to have them in dataframe with timestamp column?

Comment: when you apply to_timestamp it produces 2022-07-02 16:53:30.375 but i need the exactly the same value 2022-07-02T16:53:30.375Z,     2022-07-02T16:53:30.3750000+00:00

Comment: @SurendiranBalasubramanian, you are confused: Timestamp type doesn't have format. Format is presentation only, and what you should ask instead is this: "how can I present my timestamps in required format in X?", where X is the tool with which you look at your timestamps. So, my question to you: what is your X?

Answer (score 1):

I chose to show you have to solve this problem with Spark SQL.

```
#
# Create sample dataframe + view
#

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
  (1,"2022-07-02T16:53:30.375Z","2022-07-02T16:53:30.3750000+00:00","2022-07-02 16:53:30.3750000+00:00"),
  (2,"2022-08-02T17:33:10.456Z","2022-08-02T17:33:10.4560000+00:00","2022-08-02 17:33:10.4560000+00:00"),
  (3,"2022-09-02T18:13:20.375Z","2022-09-02T18:13:20.3750000+00:00","2022-09-02 18:13:20.3750000+00:00"),
  (4,"2022-09-02T19:23:90.322Z","2022-09-02T19:23:90.3220000+00:00","2022-09-02 19:23:90.3220000+00:00")
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["Tran_id", "Tran_date1", "Tran_date2", "Tran_date3"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# make temp hive view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("sample_data")

# show schema
df1.printSchema()
```

Instead of creating a file on my Azure Databrick's storage, I decided to use an array of tuples since this is a very simple file.

We can see from the image below that the last three fields are strings.

[image]

The code below uses spark functions to convert the information from string to timestamp.

See this link for Spark SQL functions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#to_timestamp

```
#
# Convert data using PySpark SQL
#

# sql stmt
stmt = """
  select
    Tran_id,
    to_timestamp(Tran_date1) as Tran_Ts1,
    to_timestamp(Tran_date2) as Tran_Ts2,
    to_timestamp(Tran_date3) as Tran_Ts3  
  from sample_data
"""

# new dataframe w/results
df2 = spark.sql(stmt)

# show schema
df2.printSchema()
```

[image]

**I totally agree with qaziqarta.**

Once the data is a timestamp, you can format it any which way you want either in the front end reporting tool (Power BI) or convert it to a formatted string in the curated zone as a file ready formatted for reporting.

See link for Spark SQL Function.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_format

See link for valid date format strings.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

The code below formats the timestamp in 3 different forms.

```
#
# Convert data using PySpark SQL
#

# sql stmt
stmt = """
  select
    Tran_id,
    date_format(to_timestamp(Tran_date1), "yyyy-MM-dd") as Tran_Fmt1,
    date_format(to_timestamp(Tran_date2), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") as Tran_Fmt2,
    date_format(to_timestamp(Tran_date3), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")  as Tran_Fmt3  
  from sample_data
"""

# new dataframe w/results
df3 = spark.sql(stmt)

# show schema
df3.printSchema()
```

Please note, we are now going back to a string format.

[image]

Here is execution and output of the above SQL to obtain formatted strings representing date, date/timestamp and date/extended timestamp.

[image]